# Получить значение из объекта объектов

Tags: php

Запутался в этих объектах, имея следующее, как получить значение id?

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) 
{ 
  ["response"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) 
  { 
    ["count"]=> int(18) 
    ["items"]=> array(1) 
    { 
        [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (7) 
        { 
            ["id"]=> int(119) 
            ["date"]=> int(1475281654) 
            ["out"]=> int(0) 
            ["user_id"]=> int(999000777) 
            ["read_state"]=> int(0) 
            ["title"]=> string(5) " ... " 
            ["body"]=> string(10) "добро" 
        } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$obj->response->items[0]->id` ?

Comment: Да, точно, там же массив, спасибо!)